# SAP: Upgrading Hybris from version 5.1.1 to 6.2

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have SAP Hybris Commerce version 5.1.1 with custom extensions installed. Now we need to upgrade it to newest version 6.2.

My question is: Can we upgrade it to 6.2 and skip all versions between 5.1 and 6.2? Or must it be done by upgrading to 5.2, then to 5.3 and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - 5.1.1 to 6.2 ought to work (I've been working on a project that's done exactly this).

You will probably have to make some changes - watch out for any customisations you've made - it might be worth reading through the release docs to have an idea of what's changed - off the top of my head the structure of add ons is one area that's a bit different between 5.1 and 6.2, but otherwise things should work OK in theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Have you faced any other difiiculties besides different add ons structure when you were working on that project?

Comment: Not especially. 5.1 uses JDK7 and 6.2 uses JDK8, otherwise it should be relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can directly update to 6.2.

It's important to regulary update your hybris version. You should not have so much gap with current version. Indeed it become tougher to migrate your custom code.

Upgrading each minor version in a row is totally useless most of the time. Only do this if you have issues you can't solve while migrating to the target version.

You should take a look at this [migration documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8be8ff7d866910149618f66c130dab3d.html) and this [guide](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c10e0f286691014a9f6c481c3d36a02.html) (it can be used even if it doesn't match your version).

Note that some stuff like promotion are totally different in hybris 6 so you can expect some trouble to migrate everything. Take care of your extensions generated with old template also.

Answer (score 0):

5.5.1 introduces JDK8 and Spring 4, I would not underestimate this change!  Depending on the size of your project I would first go for 5.5.1. Also notice the MySQL change for 6.2 (5.6). Don't forget to declare deployment tables in your items.xml. Search for "third-party compatibility" and "release notes" on the wiki. Also try shifting to the backoffice since the hMC is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can migrate directly 6.2.

The time and difficulty depends on your custom code (and how much it respects good practices : naming conventions, usage of service, architecture respect...etc)

You might also consider that HMC is deprecated in 6.2